# How to show the current time in Phaser framework?

Tags: phaser-framework

I can't seem to find an example on how to show the current time in Phaser framework. I've went through the [examples](http://phaser.io/examples) on the official site, and all I could come up are the example where the timer is counting down, or up toward something (like [this example](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/time/custom-timer), for example, pun intended :)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example will work. However, it will check the time every update (run once for every frame), which is more computationally expensive and will probably slow down your game. Here's a solution with a timer that updates the time every second:

```
var timeString;
var timeText;

function create() {
    var style = { fill : "#FFFFFF" };
    timeText = game.add.text(200, 200, timeString, style);

    var timer = game.time.create();
    timer.repeat(1 * Phaser.Timer.SECOND, 7200, updateTime, this);
    timer.start();
}

function updateTime() {
    var time = new Date();

    var hours = time.getHours();
    var minutes = time.getMinutes();
    var seconds = time.getSeconds();

    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    timeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    timeText.text = timeString;
}
```

[Link to Phaser Sandbox with this example](http://phaser.io/sandbox/edit/RupaBYXO)

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, I'm marking your answer as correct one.

Answer (score 2):

*Since I really didn't find an official example, I'm putting it here, just for further reference so it may help someone who will be searching for the same exact query words as I did.*

It seems that it was easier than I thought it would be. Simply, update the text in the `update` method with a JavaScript function that returns needed time info using `Date` object:

```
var timeText = game.add.text(10, 10, "00:00:00");
function update(){
    timeText.setText(getCurrentTime());
}

function getCurrentTime(){
    var currentdate = new Date(); 
    var time = currentdate.getHours() + ":"  + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds();
    return time;
}
```

Comment: Would this not cause any performance limitations since it's constantly being called (around 3600 times a minute).